# How do I decompress files using Huffman Compression?

Tags: python, compression, huffman-code

I have written a Huffman Compression Algorithm in python, but so far I have only managed to do the compression part (by making a priority queue using heapq). I have created a class called HuffmanCoding which takes in the text to compress. I know that one way of decompressing is saving a dictionary with the characters and their codes to the compressed text file, but I am not sure about how I should do this (especially because my compressed text is stored in a binary file). Does anyone have any pointers or advice to how I could go about decompressing? Below is my compression code.

````
class HeapNode:
    def __init__(self, char, freq):
        self.char = char
        self.freq = freq
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __lt__(self, other):  # if the frequency of one character is lower than the frequency of another one
        return self.freq < other.freq

    def __eq__(self, other):  # if two characters have the same frequencies
        if other == None:
            return False
        if not isinstance(other, HeapNode):  # checks if the character is a node or not
            return False
        return self.freq == other.freq


class HuffmanCoding:
    def __init__(self, text_to_compress):
        self.text_to_compress = text_to_compress  # text that will be compressed
        self.heap = []
        self.codes = {}  # will store the Huffman code of each character
        

    def get_frequency(self):  # method to find frequency of each character in text - RLE
        frequency_Dictionary = {}  # creates an empty dictionary where frequency of each character will be stored

        for character in self.text_to_compress:  # Iterates through the text to be compressed
            if character in frequency_Dictionary:
                frequency_Dictionary[character] = frequency_Dictionary[character] + 1  # if character already exists in
                # dictionary, its value is increased by 1
            else:
                frequency_Dictionary[character] = 1  # if character is not present in list, its value is set to 1

        return frequency_Dictionary

    def make_queue(self, frequency):  # creates the priority queue of each character and its associated frequency
        for key in frequency:
            node = HeapNode(key, frequency[key])  # create node (character) and store its frequency alongside it
            heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)  # Push the node into the heap

    def merge_nodes(
            self):  # creates HuffmanTree by getting the two minimum nodes and merging them together, until theres
        # only one node left
        while len(self.heap) > 1:
            node1 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # pop node from top of heap
            node2 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # pop next node which is now at the top of heap

            merged = HeapNode(None, node1.freq + node2.freq)  # merge the two nodes we popped out from heap
            merged.left = node1
            merged.right = node2

            heapq.heappush(self.heap, merged)  # push merged node back into the heap

    def make_codes(self, root, current_code):  # Creates Huffman code for each character
        if root == None:
            return

        if root.char != None:
            self.codes[root.char] = current_code
            

        self.make_codes(root.left, current_code + "0")  # Every time you traverse left, add a 0 - Recursive Call
        self.make_codes(root.right, current_code + "1")  # Every time you traverse right, add a 1 - Recursive Call

    def assignCodes(self):  # Assigns codes to each character
        root = heapq.heappop(self.heap)  # extracts root node from heap
        current_code = ""
        self.make_codes(root, current_code)

    def get_compressed_text(self, text):  # Replaces characters in original text with codes
        compressed_text = ""
        for character in text:
            compressed_text += self.codes[character]
        return compressed_text

    def pad_encoded_text(self, compressed_text):
        extra_padding = 8 - len(compressed_text) % 8  # works out how much extra padding is required
        for i in range(extra_padding):
            compressed_text += "0"  # adds the amount of 0's that are required

        padded_info = "{0:08b}".format(extra_padding)
        compressed_text = padded_info + compressed_text
        return compressed_text

    def make_byte_array(self, padded_text):

        byte_array = bytearray()
        for i in range(0, len(padded_text), 8):
            byte_array.append(int(padded_text[i:i + 8], 2))

        return(byte_array)

    def show_compressed_text(self):

        frequency = self.get_frequency()
        self.make_queue(frequency)
        self.merge_nodes()
        self.assignCodes()

        encoded_text = self.get_compressed_text(self.text_to_compress)
        padded_encoded_text = self.pad_encoded_text(encoded_text)

        byte_array = self.make_byte_array(padded_encoded_text)
        return bytes(byte_array)

    def remove_padding(self, padded_encoded_text):  # removes the padding that was added
        padded_info = padded_encoded_text[:8]
        extra_padding = int(padded_info, 2)

        padded_encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[8:]
        encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[:-1 * extra_padding]

        return encoded_text```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to send a description of the Huffman code along with the data. Second you need to use that on the decompression end to decode the Huffman codes.

The most straightforward way is to traverse the tree, sending a 1 bit for every node encountered and a 0 bit followed by the symbol bits for every leaf.  On the decompression end you can read that and reconstruct the tree. Then you can use the tree, traversing to the left or right with each bit of data until you get to a leaf. Emit the symbol for that leaf, and then start back at the root of the tree for the next bit.

The way this is usually done in compression libraries is to discard the tree and instead keep and send just the code lengths for every symbol, compressing that as well. Then on both the compression and decompression side, the same canonical Huffman code is constructed from the lengths. Then a table look up can be used for decoding, for speed.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, I have to store for example a dictionary of each character and their respective Huffman code along with the compressed text right? I don't really understand keeping the code lengths though - how can you construct Huffman code just from the code lengths? (sorry if my question doesn't make sense!)

Comment: No, I'm not saying send every character and code. You could, but that would be wasteful. You only need _2n-1_ bits + the bits for the _n_ coded characters to describe the tree.

Comment: As for constructing a Huffman code from the lengths, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code .